# Using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with Cloudify 3.1

Tags: cloudify

I have an application which uses old packages and runs on Ubuntu 10.04 lucid. I am trying to use cloudify 3.1 to deploy it on openstack. However, it seems cloudify does not find lucid agent. Does cloudify support lucid distribution? any idea what is the problem and how could I solve it ? This is the error message I got:

Task failed 'worker_installer.tasks.install' -> **RecoverableError("FabricRunnerException: Command 'wget -T 30 http://10.67.79.2:53229/packages/agents/Ubuntu-lucid-agent.tar.gz -O /home/ubuntu/cloudify.mysql_host_2d7a6/agent.tar.gz' exited with code 1: [ubuntu@10.67.79.18:22] out: --2015-07-08 23:49:56-- http://10.67.79.2:53229/packages/agents/Ubuntu-lucid-agent.tar.gz\n[ubuntu@10.67.79.18:22] out: Connecting to 10.67.79.2:53229... connected.\n[ubuntu@10.67.79.18:22] out: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found\n[ubuntu@10.67.79.18:22] out: 2015-07-08 23:49:56 ERROR 404: Not Found.\n[ubuntu@10.67.79.18:22] out: \n[ubuntu@10.67.79.18:22] out: \n",) [attempt 1]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudify 3.1 does not support Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid by default. You need to built your own agent for that distribution.

[Here](http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.1/agents-packager.html) is the documentation on how to do that for Cloudify 3,1.

If you already have built a custom agent for Ubuntu Lucid, and the package is located there, I would ssh into the machine that is seeing that error and try to curl that URL and verify that the URL is reachable.